# Copy a 2-dimensional pixel array to a Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Using the Javascript canvas element, is it possible to copy a 2-dimensional array of RGB values to a canvas?

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
<script type = "text/javascript">

//copy the following array to the canvas:
var arr1 = [
[[255, 255, 255],[200, 200, 0],[200, 200, 200]],
[[200, 0, 0],[200, 200, 0],[200, 200, 0]],
[[200, 200, 0],[200, 0, 0],[200, 200, 0]]
]

<script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found a relevant example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6CHB/1/ Now I just need to modify it so that it will copy an array to the canvas.

Comment: The inverse of this would be getting the pixels from the canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727090/return-pixels-of-a-canvas-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getImageData`/`putImageData`. Just calculate the right index (it's RGBA values in one big array): http://jsfiddle.net/zjypd/ (the jsFiddle has an enlarged canvas to show the pixels).

```
var arr1 = [
    [[255, 255, 255],[200, 200, 0],[]],
    [[200, 0, 0],[200, 200, 0],[200, 200, 0]],
    [[200, 200, 0],[200, 0, 0],[200, 200, 0]]
];

var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

var height = arr1.length;
var width = arr1[0].length;

var h = ctx.canvas.height;
var w = ctx.canvas.width;

var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
var data = imgData.data;  // the array of RGBA values

for(var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        var s = 4 * i * w + 4 * j;  // calculate the index in the array
        var x = arr1[i][j];  // the RGB values
        data[s] = x[0];
        data[s + 1] = x[1];
        data[s + 2] = x[2];
        data[s + 3] = 255;  // fully opaque
    }
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: One of the arrays in my example was empty - sorry for the typo! (The empty array should be `[200, 200, 200]`).

Comment: To change the array scale (in this example), you only need to change the pixel value in the css section. :)

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I just realized you can better use `(0, 0, w, h)` instead of the hardcoded `(0, 0, 3, 3)` for the arguments of `getImageData`.

Comment: It's also possible to resize the canvas so that it matches the dimensions of the array: http://stackoverflow.com/a/331462/975097

Comment: Here's my first attempt at getting the array to resize automatically. I'm still not sure whether it's working correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/zjypd/4/

Comment: @AndersonGreen: It looks fine. The only issue I can think of is the white space above the canvas. That's because `<canvas>` is an inline element, so it is positioned at the text baseline.

Comment: I meant to write "canvas" when I wrote "array" in the above post.

Comment: I filled the array with a horizontal stripe pattern, and the canvas showed a diagonal stripe pattern instead. There must be an error somewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/zjypd/5/

Comment: I've found the problem: your code only works properly for square arrays of RGB values. It needs to be modified so that it will work with arrays of other dimensions (such as 100x200.)

Comment: @Anderson Green: Woops, you're completely right. The index calculation is wrong - it has to be `4 * i * w + 4 * j`: advancing one height pixel means advancing one row, which is one full *width*. This just wasn't noticeable in the case `w === h`.

Comment: @pimvdb of course what you _should_ have done was just set `s = 0` outside the loops and just increment it with every write.  There's absolutely no need to recalculate it for every pixel, since the offset into `data` just goes up monotonically.