# Fast way to make RGB array into RGBA array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

An emulator I am working with internally stores a 1-dimensional framebuffer of RGB values. However, HTML5 canvas uses RGBA values when calling putImageData. In order to display the framebuffer, I currently loop through the RGB array and create a new RGBA array, in a manner [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13826397).

This seems suboptimal. There has been much written on performing canvas draws quickly, but I'm still lost on how to improve my application performance. Is there any way to more quickly translate this RGB array to an RGBA array? The alpha channel will always be fully opaque. Also, is there any way to interface with a canvas so that it takes an array of RGB, not RGBA, values?

Comment: I see quite the assumption, did you actually run into problems with performance?

Comment: @JanJongboom he's working on an emulator, eeking every last bit of performance out of it is probably a given.

Comment: What is your source array's type ? [], Int8Array, Uint8Array, ArrayBuffer ?

Comment: @Vincent Good call. I'm not totally sure off the top of my head, I'll look, but the destination is a UInt8ClampedArray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to use plain RGB, but the loop in that code could be optimised somewhat by removing repeated calculations, array deferences, etc.

In general you shouldn't use `ctx.getImageData` to obtain the destination buffer - you don't normally care what values are already there and should use `ctx.createImageData` instead.  If at all possible, re-use the same raw buffer for every frame.

However, since you want to preset the alpha values to `0xff` (they default to `0x00`) and only need to do so once, it seems to be much most efficient to just fill the canvas and then fetch the raw values with `getImageData`.

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; // implicit alpha of 1
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
dest = ctx.getImageData(0, 0).data
```

and then for each frame for can just leave the alpha byte untouched:

```
var n = 4 * w * h;
var s = 0, d = 0;
while (d < n) {
    dest[d++] = src[s++];
    dest[d++] = src[s++];
    dest[d++] = src[s++];
    d++;    // skip the alpha byte
}
```

You could also experiment with "loop unrolling" (i.e. repeating that four line block multiple times within the `while` loop) although results will vary across browsers.

Since it's very likely that your total number of pixels will be a multiple of four, just repeat the block another three times and then the `while` will only be evaluated for every four pixel copies.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I am indeed using a 1D array. Updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Perhaps this is picky, but is there any way to not update the alpha channel every single time this loops through? Maybe starting with an array the size of the canvas filled with 0xFF and updating the RGB channels, but skipping the alpha?

Comment: A newly created canvas will have alpha 0. You could use `fillRect` to fill it with (opaque) white, though.

Comment: @CaseyChu yes, you're right.   The colour you fill with doesn't matter, so long as the Alpha component is 255.  Using `#000000` would do as the alpha is implicitly `0xff`.

Answer (score 2):

Both ctx.createImageData and ctx.getImageData will create a buffer, the later (get) will be slower since it has also to copy the buffer.
This jsperf : http://jsperf.com/drawing-pixels-to-data
confirms that we have a like 33% slowdown on Chrome, and 16 times slower on Firefox (FFF seems to byte-copy when Chrome copy with 32 or 64 bits move).

i'll just recall that you can handle typed array of different types, and even create a view on the buffer (image.data.buffer).
So this may allow you to write the bytes 4 by 4.

```
var dest = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
var dest32 = new Int32Array(dest.data.buffer);
var i = 0, j=0, last = 3*width*height;
while (i<last) {
      dest32[j] = src[i]<<24 + src[i+1] << 16 
                   + src[i+2] << 8 + 255;
      i+=3; 
      j++;
}
```

You will see in this jsperf test i made that it is faster to
write using 32 bits integers : 
http://jsperf.com/rgb-to-rgba-conversion-with-typed-arrays
notice that there is a big issue in those tests : since this test is
awfull in terms of garbage creation, accuracy is so-so. 
Still after many launch, we see that we have around 50%
gain on write 4 vs write 1.

Edit : it might be worth to see if reading the source with a DataView wouldn't speed things up.
but the input array has to be a buffer (or have a buffer property like a Uint8Array).
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/DataView)

do not hesitate to update the fiddle with such a try.

Edit 2  : 
I don't understand i re-ran the test and now write 4 is slower : ???  and after, faster again : -------

Anyway you have great interest in keeping the dest32 buffer under your hand and not
create a new one each time anyway, so since this test measure the Int32Array creation, it does not correspond to your use case.

Comment: ah, _that's_ the bit that Ken was missing - you need to access the `.buffer` property of the `Uint8ClampedArray` in order to alias it with a 32-bit array.  However the code will now assume a particular endian-ness.  I had looked to see if there was a way to access the underlying `ArrayBuffer` of the canvas but hadn't found it.